# NullPointerException on click of imageButton

Tags: android

I am new in Android. To create a slide I used `PageAdapter`. Below is my code.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4; //set  number of swipe screens here
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup collection, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.activity_slide; //set which layout will show on load
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.slide_2; //what layout swiping shows
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.slide_3; //what layout swiping shows
                break;
            case 3:
                resId = R.layout.slide_4; //what layout swiping shows
                break;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup arg0, final int arg1, final Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(final View arg0, final Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }
}
```

My problem is in `layout.slide_4` I placed a `Button` and I want to open new activity on click of that button. So I wrote below code oncreate:

```
Button btnExplore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    btnExplore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            Intent i = new Intent(IntroSlide.this, StartScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**Logcat**

```
01-18 14:58:58.267 22740-22740/com.totsmart.pedronapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x536dd160)
01-18 14:58:58.287 22740-22740/com.totsmart.pedronapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.totsmart.pedronapp, PID: 22740
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.totsmart.pedronapp.IntroSlide$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(IntroSlide.java:59)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting `NullPointerException`. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Whenever you talk about any exception, you should post logcat error trace also. Roughly I suspect `R.id.imageButton` is not in the currently loaded layout. Can't confirm unless I see the logcat error.

Comment: Please, post your logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @rohit5k2: yes `R.id.imageButton` is not in currently loaded layout

Comment: ImageButton? But above You show the code for a Button, not an ImageButton....

Comment: If its not loaded then you will get NPE. No other way than loading the layout first.

Comment: Did you make sure that you have the correct id of the button?

Comment: sorry it is Button not ImageButton

Comment: @rohit5k2: that layout is my 4th slide so i can't load it first.

Comment: Then keep a null check before you set the `onClickListener`

Comment: After looking at the logcat error. I see error is in line **59** of `IntroSlide.java`. Can you please point that line?

Comment: IntroSlide.java:59. Please mark where line is error ?

Comment: `btnExplore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` here

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i added null check before onClickListener but now on click nothing happening.

Comment: Is your button present in ViewPager or  present in any other view??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments your layouts are being loaded at runtime. So if any layout is not loaded and you try to use any  view of that layout you will get `NullPointerException`.

I would suggest to add a null check before setting `onClickListener` like this

```
Button btnExplore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
if(btnExplore != null)
{
    btnExplore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            Intent i = new Intent(IntroSlide.this, StartScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** You should put all these codes in a separate method and call that method each time you load a new layout.

**Update:** Better solution would be to divide the listener codes based on individual layouts and keep different method for different layout's view listeners. After this, call appropriate method from your switch statement. Also you will have to move the following code in individual cases.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
return view;
```